# How is the pronunication of 为什么呀?

Tags: mandarin

I was watching this youtube lesson
https://www.youtube.com/shorts/LHOX4m2ToiI

And shortly into the video the boy says: *为什么呀*

But it certainly sounds more like: *"wei r meya"*

Did I hear that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You heard that right. The boy pronounced it with liaison and a bit nasal voice. Such a manner of articulation is used widely by northerners in China. In contrast, most southerners are not able to pronounce such a mode. The standard pronunciation of "为什么呀" is "wei she me ya" in standard mandarin.